# Pulling and working from git branch

Tags: git, branch

I'm trying to fully understand git branching, but the part of the workflow that I don't grasp yet is how to pull an existing branch. I've cloned a repo and used `git pull origin [branch]`, and then checked out into it, but I still only have the master files. I'm obviously missing something. Do I need to update the remote origin? I don't want to merge the branch yet.

I've Googled around, but everything I found shows how to create branches locally and then merge them, but not work off existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pull would *merge* a remote tracking branch into the current one (master)

Do a git fetch to get all the branches: see them with

```
git branch -avv
```

(`-a` for "all", local and remote tracking branches fetched from the remote repo)

Then, to work on any of those remote tracking branches:

```
git checkout -b abranch -t origin/abranch
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm starting over to do it right. So, after cloning the repo, I'd use `git branch -avv`, then `checkout` into the specific one? Does fetching them actually copy the files for all the branches locally? Thanks!

Comment: @MarioParra A clone has already copied everything. A fetch simply ensure you are up-to-date. Then you pick and choose the remote tracking branch you wish to work on by creating a local branch starting from it.

Comment: @MarioParra Interesting read: http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/#git_clone

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that a clone included branches too. So, the `branch -avv` command will update all local branches? What's the difference over doing a `pull origin`? Thanks

Comment: `branch -avv` merely lists what has already been cloned or fetched. `git pull` fetches *and* merges to the current branch.

Comment: Got it. So, the correct workflow in my case is cloning, listing branches, checking out into a branch–and then how do I push my changes for that specific branch to GitHub? A standard `push` or? Thanks

Comment: @MarioParra A simple `git push` will be enough, because the local branch is already tracking the remote one (that is the `--track` of the command `git checkout -b abranch --track/-t origin/abranch`). With that, Git knows where and to what to push the local branch.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!